# Suppose $Y=f(Z,V)$, then is $E[f(1,V)|Z]$ defined for $Z\neq 1$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose random variable $Y=1(\alpha Z+V>0)$, where $Z$ is a Bernoulli random variable, $V$ is a normal random variable, $\alpha$ is a constant and $1(\cdot)$ is the indicator function. When $Z=1$, let the corresponding $Y$ be denoted as $Y_1=1(\alpha +V>0)$. My question is, is $E(Y_1|Z)$ well-defined for any $Z\in\{0,1\}$?

One interpretation is that $E(Y_1|Z)$ is well-defined and  $E(Y_1|Z)=E(1(\alpha +V>0)|Z)$ for any $Z\in\{0,1\}$, it's all about how random variables $V$ and $Z$ are related.

On the other hand, I feel that since $Z$ is already fixed at 1, then only $E(Y_1|Z=1)$ is meaningful, while $E(Y_1|Z=0)$ is undefined since the conditioning set is empty.

Which interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question: suppose $Y=\mathbf{1}(X>0)$, then $E(Y)=\text{Pr}(X>0)$, as $Y$ is a Bernoulli random variable. If $X=Z+V$, the situation is the same. The only problem is defining the probability distribution for $X$ in order to specify $\text{Pr}(X>0)$. If $Z=1$ and $V\sim$ Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $X\sim$ Normal$(\mu+1,\sigma^2)$.

If $Z=\alpha$, a constant, and $Y\sim$ Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $E(Y)=1-\Phi(\dfrac{\mu+\alpha}{\sigma})$, with $\Phi(\cdot)$ being the cumulative probability function for the Normal$(0,1)$. If $X=\alpha Z+V$, $Z$ being a Bernoulli r.v. and $V\sim$ Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$, your problem is figuring out the distribution of $X$ in order to fully specify $E(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not interested in $E(Y)$ though, I'm interested in $E(Y|Z)$. In particular, I want to know when $Z=1$, is $E(Y|Z=0)$ defined? If yes, when $Z=1$ what is $E(Y|Z=0)$?

Comment: If $Z=1$, $X=Z+V$, the the conditional distribution of $X|Z=0$ doesn't make much sense for me.  $E(Y|Z=0)$ is just a consequence of that.  In what context this question is arising?

Comment: Thanks. I agree. It's just that I read about this notation in a manuscript which confuses me.